# IPython - change environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, ipython

I try to get iPython and the notebook to work but I get this message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`. I read this: [Ipython on Windows](http://wiki.ipython.org/IPython_on_Windows):

- Recent versions of IPython (as of at least 0.12.1) use %USERPROFILE% (typically C:\Users\ under Vista and 7, or C:\Documents and Settings\ under XP) and store your configuration in a %USERPROFILE%.ipython directory. Previous versions of IPython have required manually setting a %HOME% environment variable.
  If you have non-ascii characters in your username and you get a UnicodeError crash on startup, you may need to manually set %HOME% to a directory with an ASCII-only name anyway (a directory like C:\home may be good enough if you're the only user of your computer). This has not been tested on recent versions of IPython, however.

I have a user name with non-ascii characters. It looks like this is the solution but how do I fix it? I'm new to this and knows where to change the variables but I do not know what to write. I have created a folder c:\ipython that I would like to use and I run Windows 7 Home Edition. Probably easy to fix if you know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: Changed environment variables: IPYTHON_DIR was set to the folder c:\ipython. Tried many times with IPYTHONDIR but it did not work.